# N prefix before string insert query codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I want to insert a unicode string with 'N' Prefix and it is worked if use:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_exmp(test)values(N'$string')");
```

but I want to use CodeIgniter directly queries(E.g $this->db->insert)

so a problem is in the insert, query saves Unicode characters question mark(?)

query:

```
$data = array('test' => 'N'.$string);
```

=> output : ?????

```
$data = array('test' => 'N'.'$string');
```

=> output : N$string

Is there any way to achieve the above insert instead of manually writing the Query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do concatenation before insertion into database

```
$updatedString = 'N' . $string;
$data = array('test' => $updatedString);
$this->db->insert($data);
```

Comment: you want store Urdu in the database.

Comment: I think this doesn't make sense to concatenate N with Urdu letter. Is it?